# Given $x+y+z=1$ Find Maximum value of $x^5y+y^5z+z^5x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$x,y,z$ are Non negative reals such that  $x+y+z=1$ Find Maximum value of $$E=x^5y+y^5z+z^5x$$

The only idea i have is $E$ can be written as $f(x,y)$ and using partial differentiation for maxima...but too lengthy

Comment: Do you know how to use Lagrangian multipliers? If so this problem is a natural candidate for them.

Comment: the maximum is given by $$\frac{3125}{46656}$$ for $$x=\frac{1}{6},y=0,z=\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: @Semiclassical: Lagrange multipliers don't help here, because (i) the algebra is too complicated; and (ii) even if you could do the algebra, you would get a minimum, not a maximum. (The maximum is attained on the boundary of the constraining surface.)

Comment: In general, one can modify the proof of Micheal Rozenberg to deduce that maximum of $x^my^n+y^mz^n+z^mx^n$ is $\dfrac{m^mn^n}{(m+n)^{m+n}}$, for positive integers $m,n$, given the same constraint on $x,y,z.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x\geq y\geq z$. Hence, by AM-GM 
$$x^5y+y^5z+z^5x\leq(x+z)^5y=5^5\left(\frac{x+z}{5}\right)^5y\leq5^5\left(\frac{5\cdot\frac{x+z}{5}+y}{6}\right)^6=\frac{5^5}{6^6}.$$
 In the case $x\geq z\geq y$ we can use the same idea.
$$x^5y+y^5z+z^5x\leq x^5z+y^5x+z^5y\leq(x+y)^5z\leq5^5\left(\frac{5\cdot\frac{x+y}{5}+z}{6}\right)^6=\frac{5^5}{6^6}$$
The equality occurs for $z=0$ and $y=\frac{x}{5}$, which gives the answer: $\frac{5^5}{6^6}$.

Comment: Can i know how did you write $x^5y+y^5z+z^5x \le (x+z)^5y$ Is this related to Rearrangement inequality

Comment: @Umesh shankar $(x+z)^5y=x^5y+5x^4yz+10x^3z^2y+10x^2z^3y+5xz^4y+z^5y\geq x^5y+y^5z+z^5x$

Comment: Hello. Is there some intuition for these specifc manipulations? Or just try try try until something works?

Comment: @Ovi Yes of course, there is something. The equality occurs for $\min\{x,y,z\}=0$ and from here we get two cases.

Comment: Maybe I should ask separate question for this but... Why does $\min\{x,y,z\}=0$ imply that we should compare with $(x+z)^5y$? And how do we know maximum is achieved when $\min\{x,y,z\}=0$ before we solve it?

Comment: There are many similar problems. Try the following. $x$, $y$ and $z$ be non-negative numbers such that $x+y+z=3$. Prove that $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x\leq4.$.